# @future method not getting called from catch block

Tags: exception, future, rollback, database.insert, calloutexception

I am calling a webservice (synchronous) and in case of CalloutException, I'm trying to create an error log in a custom object. The problem is, the record insertion is happening in a future method and after an exception has encountered, the method is not getting called. 
In case, I remove the @future annotation, the record does not get committed to the database.
Has anyone faced similar issue and is there any workaround?

```
try{
     String updateResult = cardService.UpdateHistory(params); //Callout
     if(String.isEmpty(updateCreditCardHistoryResult) || String.isBlank(updateCreditCardHistoryResult)){
        mapResultUpdateCC.put('error', //Some string);
        handleErrorFuture(recordId, params..); //Creates error log record. No problem here
     }
    }catch(CalloutException ex){
        mapResultUpdateCC.put('exception', ex.getMessage());
        handleErrorFuture(recordId, params..); //@future not getting called
        System.debug('##Exception at UpdateHistory: '+ex.getMessage()); //Executing
    }
@future
public static void handleErrorFuture(String recId, params..){
     //Some logic
     List<ErrorLog__c> errList = collectErrors(params);
     if(errList.size()> 0){
       Database.insert(errList, true);
       //Could see the Id when @future annotation is removed. Does not get committed to DB
       System.debug('##errList: '+ errList.get(0));}
```

Comment: Just to confirm you cannot call a method annotated with future from a method that also has the future annotation. Nor can you call a trigger from an annotated method that calls another annotated method. Is your webservice method itself a future method or called from another method that's future?

Comment: No it is not. That's why I mentioned synchronous.

Comment: Could you show the code, please? This is the expected behavior if the exception is re thrown and a rollback occurs.

Comment: @DavidReed I have updated the sample code. I have created the error log record from caller method. But I don't understand why future method would not get called. My understanding was it would allow DML as I have separated the transaction. For non-future method the rollback is understandable.

Comment: Enqueuing of future methods is also rolled back when a transaction rollback occurs. I don't think there is enough context here to show you exactly where the issue is, but I think there's another exception being thrown or that your "real" code re-throws an exception in the same transaction that causes a rollback.